# Avoid multiple request java web applicaiton

Tags: java, internet-explorer, httprequest

Third party integration, browser redirection function is triggering multiple request (only IE), 2 requests within 2 nano sec difference. I am  using request attribute to deduct duplicate request and processing correct request(first request), duplicate request is sending error message. Unexpectedly, the browser is getting an error on the first request and stops further process(redirect to another component due to error).

Because error response is sending immediately, correct request is taking few nano seconds for processing the business logic.

How can I stop the duplicate request?  Can I put `Thread.sleep(20 sec)` in error request , so duplicate request will be redirected after 20 sec by that time correct request will be processed and redirected to browser.

Is this advisable?

Comment: Your question is very hard to read and understand but if I understand you correctly, the solution is: don't send an error message for the second request. Just do nothing, but don't send an error message.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your problem is : have 2 requests and they send them together to your web application, but 1 of requests got error message.

If it's correct. The solution will be depend on the expected of the client, what's kink of response they expect on this case. We have 2 ways to go :

1. Return the error message when 1 message have problem to the client
2. Ignore error request, and send the response for the second request.

In my point of view , don't use this one :

> Thread.sleep(20 sec)

What's happen if your request take more than 20 sec to process.
Hope it helps.

Comment: ie browser specific version  meta refresh tag triggering 2 requests. application browser redirection flow is 1) third party component -> 2) component a (process bus logic) -> 3) component b. here component a is getting 2 request. here how can i ignore second error request ? browser is triggered 2 request and waiting for response.

Comment: if i hold one request for 20 sec, another request will be process then browser will get response then redirect to component b. after 20 sec error request will be ignored by browser